# не отправляется POST запрос через CURL

Tags: php, curl

есть код , но при отправке , сервер не получае мой запрос ввиде json,прилетает пустой , в чем может быть проблема

```
function curl_connect($url, $method, $dataPost=''){
            $proxy = 'http://какой то адерс';
            $proxy_port = '8081';

            $ch = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);    
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataPost); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json')); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);


            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch); 
            return $result;
    }
```

Comment: а в `$dataPost` у вас что? `curl_getinfo($ch)` что показывает?

Comment: @InDevX 
curl_getinfo($ch) показывает
`[url] => какой-то адрес
    [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => 0 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0[namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0[size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0[speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )`

Comment: Код `http_code => 0` значит что соединение было закрыто до того, как  был возвращён какой-то результат (тут вариантов много, возможно сервер не находит, возможно сервер настроен не правильно). Попробуйте добавить `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`

Comment: @InDevX так дает ответ ввиде ошибки что ваши значения пусты